# How can I find the boundary surface in this image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to image processing. I want to find the surface between black and white pixels which separates them. Here is the link of image. 
The size of image is (21,900,900)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zUWK0Fb_n6f1JZou5mrUJq0x3h2X8mBK/view?usp=sharing

I tried to use boundarymask command of MATLAB in one plane of image but I am getting noise and also it works for 2d image only. Please suggest me how to find boundary 3d surface  here. Thank you. 
This is the output image after applying boundarymask.

[image: How to find surface boundary between white and black]

Comment: After removing noise in a way similar to suggested by Max (though I’d use a 3D median filter instead), apply an erosion with a 3x3x3 kernel. The difference between the image and the eroded image is the surface you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to get rid of your noise. Since you got some kind of salt and pepper noise you can to that using the median filter on a 2D-image with `medfilt2()` in matlab. After that you can use an edge ditector to find your edge pixels. The code for this could look like this. If you want the surface, you need to loop this, over the 3rd dimension of your 3D-image. The code will look like this:

```
for ii=1:16
    I=imread('image.tif',ii);
    I_bs=boundarymask(I);
    I_filt=medfilt2(I_bs,[7 7]);
    boundarysurface(:,:,ii)=edge(I_filt,'Canny');
end
```

The edge detector I used here is certainly overkill for this easy case, but was the easiest thing I could think of in short term. If performance is relevant let me know, and I will give you another approach.

Comment: I think you missunderstood something. My input image is 3d attached in google drive link. The showed picture is output image after applying to boundary mask. The edge in 2d becomes surface in 3d. Thanks for the answer. I will try to pre processed with median filter.

Comment: well in that case I don't really understand your problem. You wanted a boundary surface, you got a boundary surface. If you want to get rid of the noise in the surface, apply the medfilt2 that I suggested. what else do you need?

Comment: @user3704712 OK, I think I got what you want now. This is the image of a boundary mask for one of the 21 one levels of the first dimension of your image and you want the surface along all 21 levels of the image, right? If so, I can change my answer to fit that need later

Comment: Yes you are right. I want the surface along all 21 levels of the image. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @user3704712 I'm sorry, I kind of forgot about this. But I adjusted my answer. Go ahead and see if it fits your need now.

Comment: You need to use a 3D operator to extract a surface from a 3D volume image. Processing plane by plane leads to 21 curves that likely don’t form a closed surface.